# How to get the URI of the frontpage?

Tags: php, uri

I use the following code to request the URI in order to display multi-language content variables. That works fine for every page that has an URI. My problem is the frontpage: For the pure domain www.domain.com without URI it doesn't work, however it works for www.domain.com/index.php. I can't figure out the right syntax for the frontpage, please help.

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'index') !== false ) {

// Frontpage
$lang['META_TITLE'] = 'Welcome to the frontpage';
$lang['META_DESCRIPTION'] = '';
$lang['META_KEYORDS'] = '';
$lang['PAGE_TITLE'] = '';
$lang['BREADCRUMB'] = '';
}
```

Comment: why not checking if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is also empty?

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in main root and paste this code .... i hope its work for you

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```